# WebView in react-native-webview: camera not working

Tags: android, react-native, webview, expo, android-camera

```
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function HealthCheck({ route }) {
    return (
        <WebView
            style={styles.webViewContainer}
            source={{ uri: route.params.url }}
            originWhitelist={["*"]}
            allowsInlineMediaPlayback
            javaScriptEnabled
            scalesPageToFit
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
            startInLoadingState
            javaScriptEnabledAndroid
        />
    );
}
```

This is my code on the webview.

The link I am trying to access needs permission to access the camera, but the problem is that the allow button on the web is not appearing on the webview.

How can I enable the camera on the webview on android? I'm using expo BTW.

Comment: Share the link.

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by forcing the app to ask for permission using the expo-camera package. This way:

```
import { Camera } from "expo-camera"

useEffect(() => {
        ;(async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
            setHasPermission(status === "granted")
        })()
    }, [])
```

i'm not even using the hasPermission state, just logging to see the effect. But now it's working